# Using HSL solvers in Omg-tools

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ipopt

Using [OMG-tools](https://github.com/meco-group/omg-tools) I wish to run an example with an HSL solver, such as the `ma57` used in [compare_distributed_optimization_quadrotors.py](https://github.com/meco-group/omg-tools/blob/master/examples/compare_distributed_optimization_quadrotors.py).

Firstly I installed OMG-tools using `pip`, which also automatically installs [Casadi](https://github.com/casadi/casadi/wiki) and [Ipopt](https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt). I then followed [the Casadi tutorial](https://github.com/casadi/casadi/wiki/Obtaining-HSL) to build HSL from source, where I can confirm that the package got installed in `/usr/local/lib`, but when running OMG-tools' example, I always get `Invalid_Option` for the selected solver. I added both the link and the environmental variable mentioned in the tutorial.

Are there any additional steps needed to **set up HSL with Ipopt** on my system, that I need to follow?

My system is running **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it running. Hopefully this short guide/advice will come in handy to someone else, apart from my future self.

First of all, when you declare a new `problem` in OMG-tools, the `options` syntax should look something like this:

```
options = {'horizon_time': horizon_time, 'solver_options': {'ipopt':{'ipopt.linear_solver': 'ma57'}}};
```

If you get a the error `Invalid_Option` printed out in the terminal on each `update_time`, the `ipopt` command wasn't recognized.

If the program exits stating, a problem with the `ma57` solver, then HSL is installed, only it can't find the correct solver - you have probably got the Archive version of HSL.

To install go to the [Casadi guide on obtaining HSL](https://github.com/casadi/casadi/wiki/Obtaining-HSL) follow the first option, building from source. Note, instead of `libblas3gf` and `liblapack3gf`, you can also use `libblas3` and `liblapack3`. Once that is done, you need to [obtain HSL](http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/ipopt/). Download the source code of one of the two packages (RC, stable) accessed using the academic license. At this step you need to fill out some forms and wait a daz or two to receive a link to the download files.

After you have prepared the environment and downloaded all the necessary files, run the configuration as described in the guide, where I recommend using the `/usr/local`, which will in terms install the package in `/usr/local/lib`:

> $> ./configure --prefix=(where_you_want_to_install) LIBS="-llapack"
>   --with-blas="-L/usr/lib -lblas" CXXFLAGS="-g -O2 -fopenmp" FCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fopenmp" CFLAGS="-g -O2 -fopenmp"

After configuring, run make and (sudo) install. Lastly, add `/usr/local/lib` to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Make sure the path is valid by echoing it to the terminal.

Now both `ma27` and `ma57` solvers should work. Form more information on which solvers and how you can use them, go to http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/.

PS: Each `Coin-HSL` package has a README of its own. Furthermore you can run `configure --help` to understand the command itself. Make sure to read both, if you encounter any problems during installation.